# Oracle 11g data pump export against network filesystem mount

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump

Are network filesytem mounts supported with data pump? I don't see any mention of them not working. However, the data pump ADD_FILE appears to hang. Here are the symptoms:

```
Filesystem  Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/d1         32G    25G   5.4G  83% /oracle-local
server:/d2 105T    49T    57T  46% /oracle-network
```

**This creates an exp.dmp file and works as expected:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/oracle-local/';

DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
 hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open( operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'exp.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
END;
```

**This creates an exp.dmp file, but the DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE appears to never finish. Just keeps spinning waiting for server to respond:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/oracle-network/';

DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
 hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open( operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'exp.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
END;
```

Comment: Exporting to an NFS mount works fine in my experience. The `add_file` step can be a bit slow but gets there. Could it be a network issue (or how the mount was done, or O/S services...) rather than an Oracle problem?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation. If there are no known issues exporting to an NFS mount, that points at a network issue. I've let the add_file step run for 5 mins without success.

Comment: Appears to be waiting on Disk file operations I/O event (p1 = 1, p2 = 0, p3 = 18). That translates to file creation of the datapump dump file.